# Rotate around center point in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to rotate my camera on the z axis (upside down) but the white Capsule always needs to be at the center of the camera (See picture).

[image]

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this if you are not familiar with trigonometry is to use the LookAt method.
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html

Set the position of the camera to where you want it, and then use LookAt to rotate the camera's transform.

Comment: when i use the lookat function my rotation freezes for some reason

Comment: You'll need to set the correct "Up" vector in the LookAt method.  The "Up" needs to be perpendicular to the vector from the camera to the capsule.

Answer (score 3):

LootAt is one option but you can also use [Transform.RotateAround()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html). In your case, it would be something like:

```
Camera.main.transform.RotateAround(cubeTransform.position, Vector3.forward, angle);
```

That means the cube's transform would rotate around the capsule's position using the z axis (forward) by an `angle` angle. Providing that your camera is already positioned to look at the capsule and the camera's forward axis is exactly the z axis.

If the camera's forward axis is not the z axis you can use `Camera.main.position - capsuleTransform.main.position` instead of `Vector3.forward`as your axis.