# How do I rotate an object around a specific point in space and point it to my cursor?

Tags: unity-game-engine

My goal is to make [this line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNaI4.jpg) rotate around the face while pointing to my cursor each frame.
What ive gotten until now is this:

```
void Update () {
    float AngleOfMouse = GetAngle (MiddleOfTheFace.position);
    transform.RotateAround (MiddleOfTheFace.position, Vector3.back, AngleOfMouse);
}
void GetAngle(){
Vector2 MousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    Vector3 ScreenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(point);
    Vector2 BulletOffset = new Vector2(MousePosition.x - ScreenPoint.x, MousePosition.y - ScreenPoint.y);
    float Angle = Mathf.Atan2(BulletOffset.y, BulletOffset.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    return Angle;
}
```

But it just rotates weirdly super fast and doesn't stop when its pointing at my cursor. Am I not approaching this right? Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `RotateAround`, this has been asked a billion times.  google or search here for 100000s of answers.  Could you delete this, to save the time of moderators

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate around center point in Unity C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33589220/rotate-around-center-point-in-unity-c-sharp)

Comment: I am using RotateAround. Nothing i found helped me in my case. I found a solution though without RotateAround but instead setting the eulerAngles of my transform directly to Quarternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,0,Angle)). Thanks anyway

Comment: cool. it might be advisable to delete since it is really a many dupe.  cheers!

Comment: cool. it might be advisable to delete since it is really a many dupe. cheers

Comment: @ThatBrianDude It probably rotates super fast because you're setting it in `Update()` try using `LateUpdate()` Also, to have it facing something you could try the [LookAt function](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html)

Comment: Have you tried http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html ?